# In Scriptures why are arrows less mentioned 'together' with bows, when they're complementary for a weapon?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches

In 2 Kings 13

> 15 And Elisha said unto him, **Take bow and arrow**. And he took unto him bow and arrows.

In Psalm 37:

> 14 The wicked have drawn out the sword, and have **bent their bow**, to cast down the poor and needy, and to slay such as be of upright conversation.

About Ephraim's apostasy in Psalm 78;

> 9 The sons of Ephraim were archers **equipped with bows,** Yet they turned back in the day of battle.
>   10 They did not keep the covenant of God And refused to walk in His law;

In Revelation 6;

> 2 And I saw, and behold a white horse: and he that sat on him had **a bow**; and a crown was given unto him: and he went forth conquering, and to conquer.

Answer (score 2):

Hebrew:

[קָ֫שֶׁת (bow) occurs 76 times.](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/7198.htm)

[חֵץ (arrow) occurs 44 times.](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/2671.htm)

Greek:

τόξον (bow) occurs once, in the verse you've quoted.

**Answer:** Arrows aren't "rarely" mentioned in the texts of the scriptures - they're mentioned just a little less often than bows. And not so little that I would personally draw any conclusions from it.

Comment: Hint: קשת and חץ are used to indicate different things in the OT. Bows indicate potential, bows and arrows emphatically indicate potential. Arrows alone usually indicates actual use of the potential, or actual blows. Arrows are sometimes used metaphorically. See if you can build on this from verse examples. The OP question is not as lame as it looks at first glance.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim Yeah, I see the metaphorical sense that 'bow' is commonly used in. But this question isn't actually about the variant uses of 'bow', it's about the "rare" use of 'arrow', which actually isn't that rare at all. I do think the question is precisely as lame as it looks at first glance.

Comment: @Abu Munir Ibn Ibrahim you are on the money!  People stampede past most 'gems' in scripture. Thanks for the recommendation. I will build on it shortly as well as provide my own answer, if I am none fitting is forthcoming.

Comment: @Steve Taylor I see what you mean, I meant 'rarely mentioned together' as one can never use either bits in isolation.

Answer (score -1):

A simple answer is that they are incompatible in most contexts, because as devices they differ in that both are complete weapons, and as distinct as a sword is from an arrow, for example.

A 'bow' for the most part refers largely to judgements in form of lifestyles based on precepts not of God, as well as entities working in the background as the fuel for such lifestyles.
Whereas arrows could be as simple a reference as hurtful words,

> Psalm 64:3
>   Who whet their tongue like a sword, and bend their bows( an insertion) to shoot their arrows, even bitter words:
>   Arrows here are the 'bitter words'

An arrow as a malevolent entity;
In Job 1, God allowed Satan to deal with Job.
Satan's instruments against man are spirit. These agents were the 'arrows'against him and all his possessions that Job attributed to God, as He didn't know the nature of His circumstances having been a wager of sorts upon his steadfastness to the kingdom of light, from the prince of darkness.

> Job 6:4
>   For the 'arrows' of the Almighty are within me, the poison whereof drinketh up my spirit: the terrors of God do set themselves in array against me.
>
> Eze 5:16
>   When I shall send upon them the evil ''arrows'' of famine, which shall be for their destruction, and which I will send to destroy you: and I will increase the famine upon you, and will break your staff of bread:

It was a decree to farmish the nation of the truth in the laws because of unfaithfulness, which lack was the famine caused by 'evil arrows'. A basic illustration of how these 'arrows' worked;

> Hosea 5:4
>   They will not frame their doings to turn unto their God: for the **spirit of whoredoms** is in the midst of them, and they have not known the LORD, just as the Spirit of the LORD amidst them, when holy.Deuteronomy 23:13.
>   These are the same 'arrows' in their 'midst'.
>   And many such writings.

A bow also as malevolent entities; 
One notable place which was misrepresented is Zechariah 9:13;

In a 'bow' referred to are entities unleashed as judgments, effectively becoming a weapon which He symbolises as a bow.
Why a bow? because a 'bow and rain' is a construct state for doctrines or ordinances that aren't to life but to death and their agents, as judgments against a wicked generation, and such as Ephraim in choosing which by 'his' calf worship over the laws of Moses, he chose a 'doctrine,' not of God and which leads to death.

These entities are often signifies as cloud because their nature is to come in hordes of them, as clouds. These are they in the book of Job by 'whom God judges' the nations, by their 'rain', that is, their ways among men.

> Job 36:31
>    "For by these He judges peoples; He gives food in abundance.

It's why Gog is said to come as 'cloud' to cover the land.
That is to work in the earth for evil, yet in this way by him God judges the nations.
This is the bow in the 'cloud' in Ezekiel 1:28. The scene prefigured a time of judgements.
However, there are both clouds for good and clouds for jugdment.

This is why the Son of man is associated with clouds both in Daniel and Revelation, because these are sentient servants, agents in salvation of man and judgement against his wicked counterpart. This is another topic, but for what it's worth I mention it.

So in;

> Zechariah 9:13
>   When I have bent Judah for me, filled the bow with Ephraim, and raised up thy sons, O Zion, against thy sons, O Greece, and made thee as the sword of a mighty man..
>
> OR
>   For I have trodden for Me Judah, A bow I have filled with Ephraim, And I have stirred up thy sons, O Zion, Against thy sons, O Javan, And I have set thee as the sword of a hero. `Young's literal trans`

He meant to 'tread' Judah with this kind of 'bow'(omitted as spurious!)that is the kind of weapon against Judah, and 'fill' or satiate that same nature of a bow with Ephraim, also as a judgement. And then, after would He raise them up as sons of Zion.
This is His way of saving them. He gives them up so as to save them.

> Micah 4:10 
>   Be in pain, and labour to bring forth, O daughter of Zion, like a woman in travail: for now shalt thou go forth out of the city, and thou shalt dwell in the field, and thou shalt go even to Babylon; there shalt thou be delivered; there the LORD shall redeem thee from the hand of thine enemies.

In which **field** the errant would fall prey to all sort of doctrines, but those that KNOW their God would be for the remnant for saving.

A bow as a reference to doctrine
Obscure writings that stick out of context such as;

> 2 Sa 1:18
>   (Also he bade them teach the children of Judah the use of the bow: behold, it is written in the book of Jasher.)

To point to the laws without fruit from doing which Israel is undone; That is the 'teaching of Judah to use the bow'
A clearer device of a bow to indicate doctrines is also in

> Psalm 78:9
>   The sons of Ephraim were archers equipped with *bows*, Yet they turned back in the day of battle.
>   10 They did not keep the covenant of God And **refused to walk in His law**

The bow are the laws of Moses that the northern kingdom abandoned for the golden calves. That was the 'battle'' they turned away from.

Now the literal history of Ephraimites is that they often looked for battle and would never shy away from a confrontation.
If anything once or twice they had a quarrel with their southern brothers for having been left out of action;

> Judges 8:1
>   And the men of Ephraim said unto him, Why hast thou served us thus, that thou calledst us not, when thou wentest to fight with the Midianites?
>   Judges 12:1
>   Then the men of Ephraim were summoned, and they crossed to Zaphon and said to Jephthah, "Why did you cross over to fight against the sons of Ammon without calling us to go with you? We will burn your house down on you."

These are some of the reasons bows and arrows appear seperately as weapons on their;

Ofcourse, literal instances not withstanding;

> 2Kings 13:15
>   And Elisha said unto him, Take bow and arrows. And he took unto him bow and arrows.